# hvac python library - Unable to authenticate

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.6, hashicorp-vault

I have following python code:

```
import hvac
import os

client = hvac.Client(url='https://vault.domain.com:8200', token='s.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
client.is_authenticated()
```

And it does not work - I get exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='vault.domain.com', port=8200): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/auth/token/lookup-self (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852)'),))
```

token is correct, because I can do vault login with it. I can telnet to https://vault.domain.com:8200 no problem.

Versions:

```
Python 3.6.9
hvac (0.10.5)
```

Any ideas?

If i add `verify=False` to client it gives

```
InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made to host 'vault.domain.com'. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning,
True
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Message `certificate verify failed` doesn't mean the client is not authenticated, it means that your client couldn't verify the server's authenticity because you're not providing it any CA cert bundle to check the server's cert against.

From [`hvac` documentation](https://hvac.readthedocs.io/en/stable/source/hvac_v1.html):

> verify (Union[bool,str]) – Either a boolean to indicate whether TLS verification should be performed when sending requests to Vault, or a string pointing at the CA bundle to use for verification.

So instead of `verify=False` you should do `verify="/path/to/ca_certs.pem"`.

When you did `verify=False`, the `True` meant that the client was correctly authenticated, so you should be able to interact with Vault this way, but not verifying the server's cert means you're vulnerable to DNS spoofing & MITM attacks.

Comment: Yes, that works!. The thing that puzzles me though is that it works without `verify` for my colleague somehow.

Comment: Your colleague probably has the CA certificate installed on their machine